# how to add Urdu language support in spring web application

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, internationalization

I need to add Urdu language support to my web application. I created two properties file like below

```
messages_en.properties
messages_ar.properties
```

and I configured my spring xml like below

```xml
<beans:bean id="messageSource"
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <beans:property name="basename" value="classpath:messages" />
        <beans:property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="localeResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.CookieLocaleResolver">
        <beans:property name="defaultLocale" value="en" />
        <beans:property name="cookieName" value="myAppLocaleCookie"></beans:property>
        <beans:property name="cookieMaxAge" value="3600"></beans:property>
    </beans:bean>

    <interceptors>
        <beans:bean
            class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
            <beans:property name="paramName" value="locale" />
        </beans:bean>
    </interceptors>
```

in  `messages_ar.properties` I put Arabic letters and I saved. If I call `locale=ar` browser doesn't display Urdu letters. I refer to [the following example  for internationalization](http://www.journaldev.com/2610/spring-mvc-internationalization-i18n-and-localization-l10n-example).

Comment: How to you call the locale? What are your browser default settings? What is the browser showing instead?

Comment: i am using firefox, its displaying as ?????, in the url i add 'locale=ar'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the following steps (after downloading the example and unpacking):

1. Added WEB-INF\classes\messages_ar.properties
2. Set encoding in WEB-INF\views\home.jsp

   **<%@ page session="false" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" %>**

Result: 
[image]

3. Reload application/browser